# Using PHP for canonical urls

Tags: php, seo, canonical-link

I set the following rule in my .htaccess file to redirect example.com/index.php to example.com

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then I set my canonical as following in the header.php for all pages:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" />
```

However I noticed the canonical url sets to index.php instead of the root.

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP_SELF is the name of the currently executing script.

For example:

> http://www.yoursite.com/example/ -- --> /example/index.php
> http://www.yoursite.com/example/index.php -- --> /example/index.php
> http://www.yoursite.com/example/index.php?a=test -- -->
> /example/index.php http://www.yoursite.com/example/index.php/dir/test
> -- --> /dir/test

If you want to generate seo friendly url to reference self source you need to set tag with site HOST+URI like this:

```php
 <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and reference. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Index.php won't hurt your MainPage SEO because Google will understand it as your main page.

About canonical rel, you should be careful about your code, php_self may add different canonical rel pages If you didn't configure 404 pages.

For example, if you don't have, about_us.php but when I enter your website doesn't redirect or give a 404 error, then there will be an about_us.php canonical URL. Sometimes google indexes that kind of page.

I always redirect 404 pages and check canonical URLs with codes.

Comment: I have a 404 added. SemRush is saying my root domain is not incorrect. I suspect it's the way the canonical php code is placed that causes this error. I am just not sure how to fix it.